# CATransiton Flicker w/ background animations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, catransition

I am using a `CATransition` to shuffle `CALayer`'s in and out of a `UIView` (the `UIView` isn't fullscreen.)  The new layer enters from the right and the old layer leaves to the left.  The `CAlayer`'s have their contents properties set to `CGImageRef`s.  Here is what I believe to be the pertinent code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];

transition.duration = transitionTime;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

transition.delegate = self;
[view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

// onDeck is the layer stage-right and is about to enter
[view.layer addSublayer:onDeck];    

// onStage is the layer currently in the middle of the view and is exiting
if (onStage)
   [onStage removeFromSuperlayer];
```

This animation occurs, there is a 1 second pause, and then a new image is animated in etc, etc.  This works beautifully in the simulator but on my 2nd generation iPod Touch, there are occasional hiccups in the animation.  Specifically, the layer being animated in will flicker on top of the currently displayed layer.  These flickers are not consistent but are noticeable.

What I've narrowed down to be the likely culprit(s) are the background animations I have going on behind this transition.  There are a few dozen `CAlayer`'s flying in and out of the full-screen view in the background.  When I remove these background animations or set the animation duration for the transition to a much higher duration (2 seconds +) the animation performs fine (I'd like the animation time to be 0.75 seconds.)

My first thought (which seems to be backed up by the above observations) is that I am pushing CoreAnimation (at least for my iPod) too hard and need to compromise.  Why I am having trouble accepting this is that the scene renders very nicely (little to no lag) aside from this occasional flicker.

If anyone has any input on this issue, or CoreAnimation optimization in general, I'd be very much appreciative!

Thanks for reading

**Update:**

Had a chance to test this on an iPhone 4 and the flickering never occurred.  Additionally, CoreAnimation instrument confirmed that, on my 2nd generation iPod Touch, I am consistently getting high 40s to low/mid 50s in FPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess: have you tried managing your CATransactions at all?

You might try bracketing your modifications to the scene like this:

```
[ CATransaction begin ]
... your animations ...
[ CATransaction commit ] ;
```

Comment: I have tried this, and there unfortunately doesn't seem to be any effect (which is interesting because I was under the impression that CATransiton had an implicit CATransaction associated with it.)

Comment: Have you tried lower res images on your layers being transitioned? You could fade to high res images once the transition is complete.

Comment: Great suggestion!  Turns out that my art assets were far too large for the size they would eventually be scaled down to.  By reducing their sizes and resolution a bit, I was able to get the necessary performance.

Comment: btw I guessed this because i started to wonder if your GPU was being (texture) bandwidth constrained..

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of all shadows (if you have any) and then check if performance improves. I've seen that shadows, particularly shadows on CAShapeLayers, have a great impact on the smoothness of animations.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  However, none of the layers have shadows.